# query an XML web service from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, xml, wcf

I've added a web service into my project in Visual Studio but I can't seem to work out how to query it.

The web service should return XML code based on the query I send to it.

This is what i'm trying

```
    Dim proxy As New mywebservice.xmlcall()

    Dim query As String = "Select * FROM table"

    Dim dataset1 As DataSet = proxy.call(query)
```

I seem to get the error

> Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.DataSet'

I'm new to WCF web services and I can't seem to work this one out

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

```
<wsdl:operation name="call">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://website.org/Ixmlcall/call" style="document" />
  <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

That's what's in the WSDL

I get this error too if i change the code like this

```
Dim dataset1 As DataSet = proxy.call()
```

> Argument not specified for parameter 'value' of 'Public Function call(value As String) As String'

**UPDATE**

I have changed a few bits now and it now returns an error

> ORA-31011: XML parsing failed ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing LPX-00229: input source is empty Error at line 0 ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272 ORA-06512: at "PM1STEP.XML_FUNCTION_CALL", line 30 ORA-06512: at line 1

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you own the web service itself, or have you just generated the proxy? On the face of it, the proxy.call is returning a string, not a DataSet. You do say it returns XML.

Comment: @Jamie: That's pretty dangerous. Exposing your underlying data store in this manner leaves it open to all sorts of injection attacks and could therefore compromise your security.

Comment: @tomasmcguinness the web service is installed on our server

Comment: @Brian any advice to make it secure would be helpful - i'm a rookie at this :)

Comment: @Jamie What is the signature of the "call" method? It accepts a string, but does it return a string type?

Comment: @tomasmcguinness how do i find out the signature?

Comment: @Jamie You said the web serivce was installed on your server, so I assume you have the source code? Did you generate the proxy using WSDL?

Comment: @tomasmcguinness yes I have the WSDL page open in front of me but I don't understand it :/

Comment: Does the "call" method return an object? You can use Intellisense in Visual Studio to check this.

Comment: @tomasmcguinness i've added a bit of code form the WSDL

Comment: @Jamie, you should look into adding authentication header attributes to your webmethods. That way you can gaurantee that they are only executable by those callers with a given username / password or public / private key mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work this one out.

I needed to pass a string to Web Service which contained XML data like this

```
<Name>Joe Bloggs</Name><Date>3 May 2011</Date>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform dynamic querying without using SQL. That way you avoid the problems with malicious sql injection.

See the following stackoverflow implementation of this;

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/143/jon-skeet-comparison

Answer (score 0):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx:

"A DataSet can read and write data and schema as XML documents."

A String is not an XML document although it probably contains one in your case. I *imagine* you need to create an XmlDocument from your string and then feed that to your Dataset.

Comment: I'm thinking along these lines to, but I don't understand why it's not causing a compile time error.

Comment: please don't post .NET 1.1 links.